# Pass variable via URLRequest

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I am displaying external swf in an other swf. I read XML file that keeps external swf path. At some point I need the result of a function in the external one. So is it possible to pass the result and fetch it over URLRequest?

Here is the code:

```
var contentLoader:Loader;
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();        
contentLoader = new Loader();       
contentLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, contentLoadingCompleteActions);
contentLoader.load(new URLRequest(url), context);
```

---

url comes from XML parser as I said before. I want to load the swf and also get the selected variable if possible.

---

A (main swf) - *imports swf via URLRequest*

B (imported swf) - *has to send a value to A*

Comment: So the function that is generating the result you need is inside the imported swf file? I don't think you can access any variables inside a swf file from the outside. Maybe there is another way if you describe more specifically what you are trying to do.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. I can handle it anyways but I am not sure about doing it over URLRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely "communicate" between those two files. First, `loader.contentLoaderInfo.content` is your actual loaded swf file. So you can call methods on it - either on the assigned class or on Timeline (not good). This way you can access properties or even functions:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, contentLoadingCompleteActions);
loader.load(new URLRequest(url), context);

function contentLoadingCompleteActions(event:Event) {
    // event.target is your loader
    var swf = event.target.content as MovieClip; // or even cast to document class!
    swf.getVariable(); // call method / get result
}
```

The same goes from the loaded swf - it can access it's parent **AFTER** it is added to stage (so it can have parent):

```
var parentObject:MovieClip = parent.parent as MovieClip; // or cast to document class
parentObject.callParentMethod();
```

You can cast to different classes (Object, Class, whatever you want) in order to communicate between them.

Comment: Um, error 1009 for swf.getVariable()
it is not getVariable in my code of course but it couldn't find it. I guess I have to tweak and adjust for my code a little bit more. Thanks...

Comment: The reason for this is that `swf` is null. **Wait** for it to load, and then access it! This code should be inside `contentLoadingCompleteActions`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: cannot find `contentLoaderInfo` property at `LoaderInfo`. I am sure I imported flash.display.Loader and it is enough.*sigh*

Comment: Oh, oh, my fault, it's already a loader info, so you just need `loader.content` or `event.target.content`. Sorry.